# Fill Irregular Area

Tags: edit-mode, blend-files, boolean-modifier

I have searched similar problems but I was not able to figure it out. I am trying to fill this area. Ideally, I want there to be a small indent so you can see the outer area is raised compared to it.

Sorry for such a silly question but I am very new to Blender.

I have tried closing it via edit mode, boolean operators in object mode, smoothing and filling in sculpt mode and separating the area and re-meshing it.

The closest I have come is the boolean but the edges are very bad and I am very unskilled with Blender.

Thank you very much

Hole attempting to fill (but I want the inside fill to be inset a bit)

[image]

Terrible attempt

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: So you want the inside fill to be similar in curvature/shape as nearby the hole I'm guessing?  I might duplicate the object, in Edit mode remove most of the vertices/faces except enough to be a bit larger than the hole,  then "fit it" just insider the hole.  You could then join the objects.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to create one or a series of new faces based on the loop of vertices around the opening...

In Edit mode, select two adjacent vertices along the opening. Then Select >> Loops >> Edge Loops. [image]

Then Vertex >> New Edge/Face from vertices. [image]

You can try doing this in sections (deselect those you don't yet want to fill) if you want more faces to work with.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Josh Hello and welcome. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos --- I work for points... that's why I'm so poor !   LOL

Answer (score 0):

Here's a second method.  I took a part of the first object (duplicated and removed lots of vertices), and then used a Shrinkwrap modifier that I could then join when fitted properly.

[image]

I used Nearest Surface point, from Inside.  There may be other choices that are better for you.

[image]